# Same author name is not allowed in subsequent references, replaced by dashes

Tags: biblatex, bibtex

I am writing a document using this [template](https://github.com/GarenSidonius/ASU-Dissertation-Template) which is using [this](https://github.com/GarenSidonius/ASU-Dissertation-Template/blob/main/src/asudis.bst) bib style file.
Having the same author for multiple references is leading to dashes as shown below.

I tried looking for `name.or.dash` or the source code which is responsible for this behavior but I could not. Kindly help!
[image]

Update: I just found out that .sty file I linked above is not used as it is part of an if/else block. `biblatex-chicago.sty` which is not even there in the project source, is being used. when I try to use `biblatex-apa` it gives me an error that `biblatex-apa.sty` is not found, wondering how is it able to locate `biblatex-chicago.sty` on its own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `usebiblatex` flag in the template is set, its bibliography setup very roughly comes down to

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  authordate,
  doi=only,
  isbn=false
]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

which indeed produces dashes instead of repeated author names

[image: Dashes for repeated Knuth]

You can use the option `dashed=false,` to turn this behaviour off and give you repeated names in the bibliography.

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  authordate,
  dashed=false,
  doi=only,
  isbn=false
]{biblatex-chicago}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Repeated Knuth]

If you want to switch the `biblatex` style completely, you need to switch from `\usepackage{biblatex-chicago}` to `\usepackage{biblatex}`. AFAIK `biblatex-chicago` styles are the only styles that are loaded via a wrapper package, all other `biblatex` styles are loaded via `biblatex`, e.g. `biblatex-apa` is used as

```
\documentclass[american]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  style=apa,
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,knuth:ct:a,knuth:ct:b,knuth:ct:c}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: APA bibliography]

Comment: wow. you solved all my problems. much thanks. love you <3

Comment: is it possible to use apa for header style as well, instead of chicago? https://13251061749486220117.googlegroups.com/attach/42881f24dc34c/headlineStyle.png?part=0.2&view=1&vt=ANaJVrEEClVrEg7-pi-q2dbu3-OXecaKzzib7RHGH5zNaCAe3OT86CX9bYyntbb_LylatWWC04vy_yIqPbbenB4FAApN1f4RtAXS-6RO9L7YFcesempzfkc

Comment: @vipin8169 Sorry, no idea. I only know about bibliographies. You may want to try asking a new question. In that case I strongly encourage you to include a proper minimal, compilable example document in your question instead of a link to a 1000-odd line template. (You may also want to explain what you mean by APA header style.) If you want to write an APA-conforming document maybe you should look into the `apa7` document class and drop the template altogether.

Comment: Could you see how to possibly indent the para. they are appearing with zero indentation. I tried looking for the piece of code that is causing indent to be 0em but could not find it. also tried setting `\setlength{\parindent}{4em}` did not work either. `parindent` does not exist in the current document, and setting it does not work.

Comment: @vipin8169 Sorry, again I have no idea at the moment. If you could post a new question with a small, compilable example document that brings the 1000 lines of your template down to a few 10s of lines that still exhibit the behaviour I'd be happy to look at it, but I don't think I'd want to fight with downloading the template and testing it right now.

Comment: I could do that but where will I post the entire code? post on github and share a link here? but that does not make sense.. what should i do to share it here?

Comment: @vipin8169 The point is *not* to post the *entire* code. Take some time to break the 1000 lines down to something containing only about 10 or 20 lines. (This can be done quite mechanically with a 'binary search', see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864.) A real MWE is usually so short that it can be included directly in the question (just like I included MWEs in the answer).

Comment: @vipin8169 Surely you can remove at least some of the code in the template that is unrelated to paragraph indentation and still reproduce the problematic behaviour you ask about. I won't pretend that this is no effort at all on your part, but posting a short example document that reproduces the issue is the best way to get people to help you quickly. And maybe you can even isolate and resolve the problem yourself while you build the MWE.

Comment: @vipin8169 That said, if you are lucky you might get an answer without posting a proper MWE if you just link to the full template. People might know what to look for and may be able to tell you what is going on without running the full document (similar to what I did in this question: I found the `biblatex-related` code and showed what was going on, but at least I wouldn't know where to start).